# How to convert a loop to Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get a Linq statement for the following scenario:

```
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    string[] splitted = line.Split(';');
    if (AccountRepository.GetAll().Where(acc => acc.Iban == splitted[1]).Count() == 0)
    {
        AccountRepository.AddAccount(new Account(splitted[1]));
        Save();
    }
}
```

My attempt was:

```
var x = lines.Select(line => line.Split(';')).Select(splitted => new Account(splitted[1]));
```

This is the code, with normal loops. How can I make one Linq Statement?

Comment: Why?  If the loops work, why change it?

Comment: Also, your question is not complete.  I suggest you read the FAQ regarding how to ask a question.  Specifically you are missing your inputs, outputs, and expected outputs.

Comment: Think you want `lines.Select( line => line.Split(";")[1]).Where( x => !AccountRepository.GetAll().Any( acc => acc.Iban == x))` or something similar. You should still perform an actual loop for the `Save` operations.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, forcing code into a Linq expression might make it harder to understand. Something like this might be more intention revealing, while still using some nice Linq constructs:

```
var existingIbans = AccountRepository
    .GetAll()
    .Select(acc => acc.Iban)
    .ToHashSet();

var allIbans = lines
    .Select(line => line.Split(';')[1]);

var newIbans = allIbans
    .Where(iban => !existingIbans.Contains(iban));

foreach (var iban in newIbans)
{
    AccountRepository.AddAccount(new Account(iban));
    Save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is very readable or clear, but if this is what you want I think this would work...

```
lines.Select(l => l.Split(';'))
     .Where(w => AccountRepository.GetById(w[1]) != null)
     .Select(sp => new Account(sp[1])) 
     .ToList() 
     .ForEach(i => AccountRepository.AddAccount(i));

Save();
```

The result is void so you have no return. You'll need some method on your account repository to figure out if an account exists. GetById is mocked up in this case so it will compile as follows:

```
public static Account GetById(string id)
    {
        if(1==1) //if account is found, return it
        return new Account(id);

        return null; //otherwise return null

    }

    public static void AddAccount(Account a)
    {
        //do something
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer if you feel your question has been successfully answered. :)

Comment: @StefanLeithenmayr Note in general that `ToList.ForEach` is considered bad practice in C# - in general, looping is faster and more efficient than LINQ, and LINQ is intended for querying, not processing.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want it in a LINQ, then this is about as close as you can get:

```
lines
  .Select(l=>l.Split(';')[1])
  .Distinct()
  .Except(AccountRepository.GetAll().Select(a=>a.Iban))
  .ForEach(l=>AccountRepository.AddAccount(new Account(l)));
Save();
```

Otherwise, I would probably opt for something more like this:

```
var ibans = lines
    .Select(l=>l.Split(';')[1])
    .Distinct()
    .Except(AccountRepository.GetAll().Select(a=>a.Iban))
    .Select(i=>new Account(i));

foreach(var account in ibans)
{
  AccountRepository.AddAccount(account);
}
Save();
```

Or if your repository has an `Add<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)` method, then:

```
var ibans = lines
    .Select(l=>l.Split(';')[1])
    .Distinct()
    .Except(AccountRepository.GetAll().Select(a=>a.Iban))
    .Select(i=>new Account(i));

AccountRepository.Add(ibans);
Save();
```

Comment: Would placing the `AccountRepository.GetAll().Select(a=>a.Iban)` outside the Linq statement be a little more efficient?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon I don't believe so.  It will iterate through both the outer sequence and the inner sequence only once.